# How to set a state-list drawable as back ground of a Button under material theme in android

Tags: android, material-design, android-theme

I am using 'Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar' as my AppTheme.I want to change the back ground to a custom state-list drawable. But the problem is that the back ground is not changing at all, it still shows the primary color as back ground.

All i want to achieve is a group of buttons having triangular shape like this.

[image: Arrow buttons]

if i use 'Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar' as my AppTheme, everything works fine. But just changing the AppTheme to Material, the button group change to normal material style button as shown.The material theme is not setting the back ground to my state-list drawable. I tried with android:backgroundTint but not able to set a state-list as background.
[image: Traditional button]

This is my xml for one button.

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/forwardbtn"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/joystick_mov_btn_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/joystick_mov_btn_size"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/joystick_mov_btn_size"
        android:background="@drawable/arrow_btn"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:rotation="270"/>
```

I don't want to change the AppTheme from material theme. I am using this approach is because i couldn't find any easy way to change the button shape other than this. I am spending too much time on this simple stuff please help..

Comment: I'd try using an ImageView/ImageButton instead, since you don't seem to need anything that a "Button" offers

Comment: Yes i agree, but it is so disgusting that i am unable to find a way to set a state-list as back ground of material button.I really want to know whether there is a way to do it?